# How to emit messages from server to specific client in Flask Socketio?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, websocket, flask-socketio

I have an app where user can submit a form and then there runs a Thread, I want to output the output of that Thread to that specific user only.

`app.py`

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        session_id = session.get('session_id', generate_session_id())
        session['session_id'] = session_id
        thread = threading.Thread(target=run_script, args=(session_id, request.form, request.files, socketio))
        thread.start()
    return render_template("index.html")

def generate_session_id():
    return str(uuid.uuid4())

def run_script(session_id, form, files, socketio):
    print(f"report started for session_id: {session_id}")
    obj = CreateReport()  # Create your CreateReport object here
    obj.session_id = session_id
    obj.socketio = socketio
    obj.start(form, files)

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    session_id = session.get('session_id', generate_session_id())
    session['session_id'] = session_id
    print(f'Client connected: {request.sid}, Session ID: {session_id}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

then the `create_report.py`

```
class CreateReport(object):
    socketio = None

    def start(self, form, files):

        self.socketio.emit('update', 'test message', room=self.session_id)
        self.socketio.emit('update', 'test message', to=self.session_id)
```

But issue is that `self.socketio.emit` emitting message to all clients

Comment: You need to save the `request.sid` value for each client, then use that as the value of the `to` argument when you emit.